# I want get the Half year or half month using sqlserver

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

This is my query

```
DECLARE @Frequencyvalue DECIMAL(18,2)
DECLARE @Frequencyunits varchar(1)
SET @Frequencyvalue=(SELECT CalibrationFrequencyValue FRO dbo.InstrumentMaster      WHERE InstrumentID=@InstrumentID)
SET @Frequencyunits=(SELECT CalibrationFrequencyUnits FROM dbo.InstrumentMaster WHERE InstrumentID=@InstrumentID)
DECLARE @HalfFrequencyvalue DECIMAL(18,2)
SET @HalfFrequencyvalue=@Frequencyvalue/2
```

Get HALF(Calibration Frequency and calibration Period) from the InstrumentMaster. [If Calibration Frequency is 1 Year, then due date should be calculated for 6 months)
Calculate next calibration date".
Just I need How to get the half Year or half month query

Comment: Try a select with a where condition. SCNR

Comment: I tried But i want the query for getting half year.

Comment: 6 months from when? Now? or do you just want the number 6 returned? Do you want to write this back to a table or is this a report?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the due date calculated from today, and @Frequencyunits is 'y','m':

```
RETURN SELECT DATEADD(CASE WHEN @Frequencyunits = 'y' THEN 'yy' ELSE 'm' END,@HalfFrequencyvalue) AS DueDate
```